# SQL avg user value on relation table

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a "free" trial period on our product. And want to get the avg. user value on a given period, some user don't extend after the free trail and some signup for our subscription.

tables users ( id, username, created_at ... ) transactions ( id, user_id, amount, created_at ...)

I need an avg. on all users ( not only the ones with a transaction as a relation )

my silly attempt

```
SELECT avg(total)
FROM (
SELECT u.id AS user_id, t.id, SUM(t.amount)/100 AS total
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN `transactions` t ON t.user_id = u.id AND (t.status='captured')
WHERE DATE(u.created) >= '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY t.id
) t
```

Free trail do not have a transaction yet .. and users who has subscribed can have multiple transactions , ( one each month ) .

Output that i want is something like

```
user_count transaction_amount avg
200        3950               19,75
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `left join` and aggregation as follows:

```
SELECT count(distinct u.id) AS user_id, count(t.id) as num_transaction,
       count(t.id)/count(distinct u.id) as avg_, 
       SUM(t.amount)/count(distinct u.id) as sum_divided_by_users
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN `transactions` t ON t.user_id = u.id
 WHERE DATE(u.created) >= '2020-01-01'
```

Comment: Cool - something like that- but i need the SUM of transactions.amount divided by the amount of users

Comment: Please check now